# Implementing a method to delete last node of a linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to delete the last node in LinkedList.
For the input: 1, 2, 3
Output should be: 1, 2

I am able to delete the node, but is there a better/more efficient way of doing so?

Please check the `removeLastNode()` method.

```
public class MyLinkedList {

Node head;
Node tail;

public void add(int number){

    Node node=new Node();
    node.setNumber(number);

    if(head==null){
        head=node;
        tail=node;  
    }
    else{
        tail.next=node;
        tail=node;          
    }

}



public void removeLastNode(){   
    Node temp=head;
    Node head1=null;
    Node tail1=null;


    while(temp.next!=null){

        Node node=new Node();
        node.number=temp.number;
        if(head1==null){
            head1=node;
            tail1=node; 
        }
        else{
            tail1.next=node;
            tail1=node;         
        }
        if(temp.next.next==null){               
            temp.next=null;
            break;
        }

        temp=temp.next;

    }
    head=head1;


}


@Override
public String toString(){
    while(head!=null){
        System.out.print(head.getNumber()+" ");
        head=head.getNext();
    }
    return "";
}

public static void main(String ar[]){

    MyLinkedList list=new MyLinkedList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.removeLastNode();

    System.out.println(list);
}




public class Node{

    Node next;
    int number;
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: You can use a double linked list where each node stored the address to the previous and next nodes

Comment: Be aware that `Java`s class `LinkedList` implements a `Doubly-linked list` by **default**, it is not a regular `linked list`! Thus you already may be good to go with Java's `LinkedList`. Or, if you need to implement it by yourself, you can look up how to do it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that `tail` is the last node.

```
public void removeLastNode() {
    if (head == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    if (head == tail) {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    } else {
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != tail) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = null;
        tail = current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Node previous`attribute to the `Node` and a `Node last` to LinkedList to get a DoubleLinkedList.

Then you can do something like

```
Node temp = List.getLast().getPrevious(); //returns the second last item
List.removeLast();    //sets the last item to null
List.setLast(temp);   //sets the last item to the second last item
List.getLast().setNext(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can delete last node from linked list by tracking previous node.

```
public int deleteAtLast() {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        Node prevoursNode = null;
        Node n = head;
        while (n.next != null) {
            prevoursNode=n;
            n = n.next;
        }
        int data = n.data;
        prevoursNode.next=null;
        return data;
    }

}
```